# How to print image along with table data in angular 13, jspdf?

Tags: angular, firebase, image, storage, jspdf

i have a registration form with user image. I'm binding the *src* propertry with firebase storage url to show user image. While downloading the form as pdf everything works fine except there is no image. With bit of changes in code, i am able to download the form as pdf but without image,  sometimes i'm getting 'error loading image' or sometimes 'Blocked by cors policy' or sometimes both.

If i use images form my assets folder, it works fine without error, but when i use storage url to show and print the user image with table data, it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?